# Arduino Automatic Clothes Line : How can I make my meet the different criteria?

Tags: arduino, project, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

So I'm a novice in programming and is helping my friend with coding an automatic clothes line for a project.

Each component works fine individually but when I put all the code together the motors are confused in which direction to go. can anyone take a look at it and give us feedback?

We have a rain sensor, light sensor, 2 switches , and a motor.

When it rains **OR** when it is dark the motors pulls the clothes in and when the the clothes reaches the end it touches switch 1 and stops the motors.

When it stop rains/sunny **AND/OR** when there light it pulls the clothes out in the open.

Here is the code I was provided:

**

```
#include <Stepper.h>
//motors
const int stepsPerRevolution = 400;
//motor speeds
Stepper myStepper = Stepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2,4, 3, 5);//clockwise
Stepper myStepper2 = Stepper(stepsPerRevolution, 5, 3, 4, 2);//counterclockwise
//rain sensor
const int capture_D =4;
const int capture_A = A0;
int val_analogique;
int led = 8;
//switches
const int switch1 = A3;
const int switch2 =A4;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 // motors
myStepper.setSpeed(60);
myStepper2.setSpeed(60);
//rain sensor
pinMode(capture_D, INPUT);
pinMode(capture_A, INPUT);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
//light sensors
unsigned int AnalogValueL;
AnalogValueL = analogRead(A5);
Serial.println(AnalogValueL);
delay(2000);
//rainsensor
if((digitalRead(capture_A) && digitalRead(capture_D)) ==LOW)
{
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  
  myStepper2.step(stepsPerRevolution); // bringclothesout
  Serial.println("DRY");
  delay(1000); 
}
  
else
{
  //when it rains the clolthes re brought in 
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.println("WET");
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);//bring clothes in 
  delay(1000);
 
}
if(AnalogValueL < 1010)
{
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  Serial.println("SUNNY");
    myStepper2.step(stepsPerRevolution);
  delay(1000);
}
else
{
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.println("Dark");
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
    delay(1000);
}
//switches
unsigned int AnalogValueS;
AnalogValueS = analogRead(switch1);
Serial.println(AnalogValueS);
delay(2000);
if(AnalogValueS <= 1000)
{
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Off");
  myStepper.setSpeed(0);
}
else
{
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.println("on");
}
unsigned int AnalogValueSS;
AnalogValueSS = analogRead(switch2);
Serial.println(AnalogValueSS);
delay(2000);
if(AnalogValueSS <= 1000)
{
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  Serial.println("ON");
 
}
else
{
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  Serial.println("Off");
   
}
*/
}//end of program
```

**

Feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my feedback:

1. Your code needs a little bit of tidying up for the sake of clarity and readability.
2. It is always recommended to declare your `Serial.begin();` at the beginning of the `setup()` function.
3. You forgot to declare the switches pins as inputs:
   `pinMode(switchX, INPUT);`  // where X = 1, 2
4. Why are you using analog pins as switch inputs? (`const int switch1 = A3`). If you are connecting ON/OFF switches here you should rather use digital pins. In case your switches are the light sensors, then they are fine (read comment 9 below). Otherwise, this:

> `AnalogValueS = analogRead(switch1);`

is wrong as you cannot read a digital switch with an `analogRead()`

Additionally, you don't say if your switches are active HIGH or active LOW, namely, if they pulse LOW when pressed and HIGH when released or viceversa.

5. One important mistake is that you are assigning pin 4 twice for different functions. First as a motor pin, then as `capture_D`:

> Stepper myStepper = Stepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2, 4, 3, 5);
> Stepper myStepper2 = Stepper(stepsPerRevolution, 5, 3, 4, 2);
> const int capture_D = 4;

6. You read the analog value in a variable declared inside the `main()` loop while you previously declared `int val_analogique` without using it. This is poor consistency.
7. Similarly, you read from analog pin A5 without previously declaring it as an `INPUT`:

> `AnalogValueL = analogRead(A5);`

8. The flow of your loop could be affected by that many `delay()` throughout the code.
9. You expressed having three sensors:

> We have a rain sensor, light sensor, 2 switches, and a motor.

It is good practice to label the pins from these sensors with a representative name from the sensor in question: e.g.:

`const int lightSensor1 = 4;`

10. In the C++ *mindset* is common practice to use `enums` to define states from a specific event or scenario. For instance:

    typedef enum {
    RAINING,
    DARK,
    NOT_RAINING,
    SUNNY
    }WEATHER_CONDITIONS;

    WEATHER_CONDITIONS currentCondition = SUNNY;

where the `typedef` means that you are creating your own data type `WEATHER_CONDITIONS` and their assigned values are 0,1, 2,... according to their order.

11. With regards to the `Stepper.h` library you are declaring two Stepper instances expecting that in that way you will reverse the direction of the motor. That is NOT how it works. According to the library (`Stepper.cpp`) to reverse the motor, you need to send a negative value as an argument to reverse its direction. Please read line 184 from this file from the library.
12. On this line:

> `if((digitalRead(capture_A) && digitalRead(capture_D)) ==LOW)`

you are attempting to read a digital value from an analog pin. While it might work if the voltage on that pin is at a logic level, this is not recommended.

13. Finally, you SHOULD connect the switches for stopping the motor to INTERRUPT pins. This is a more effective way to detect when the switch has been pressed and take immediate action by changing a state. You would have to use pins 2 and 3 (INT0 and INT1).

This is my take on this code. Compiled correctly but UNTESTED!

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Stepper.h>

/*Constants*/

//motor speeds
const int stepsPerRevolution = 400;

/*Pinout declarations*/
// Motor pins
const int motorPins[4] = {2, 3, 4, 5};

//rain sensor
const int capture_D = 4;   // capture_D
const int capture_A = A0;  // A0

const int lightSensor = A5;

//switches
const int switch1 = 9;   // Previously: A3   So this is an analog switch?
const int switch2 = 10;  // Previously: A4    You should assing this to other two digital pins

//Led
const int led = 8;

/*Custom variables*/
typedef enum {
    DARK,
    SUNNY
} LIGHT_CONDITIONS;

LIGHT_CONDITIONS lightState = SUNNY;

const char* lightLabels[] = {"DARK",
                             "SUNNY"};

typedef enum {
    DRY,
    WET
} HUMIDITY_CONDITIONS;

HUMIDITY_CONDITIONS humidityState = DRY;

const char* humidityLabels[] = {"DRY",
                                "WET"};

typedef enum {
    CW,   // Let's assume that this is bring them in
    CCW,  // this is take them out
    STOP
} MOTOR_DIRECTION;

MOTOR_DIRECTION currentDirection = STOP;  // This declares a default state

const char* directionLabels[] = {"Clothes In",
                                 "Clothes Out"};
/*General variables*/
int rawLightValue;

// Objects declaration
Stepper myStepper = Stepper(stepsPerRevolution,
                            motorPins[0],
                            motorPins[1],
                            motorPins[2],
                            motorPins[3]);

void activateMotor(int direction) {
    switch (direction) {
        case MOTOR_DIRECTION::CW:

            myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);
            currentDirection = CW;

            break;

        case MOTOR_DIRECTION::CCW:

            myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);

            currentDirection = CCW;

            break;

        case MOTOR_DIRECTION::STOP:
            currentDirection = STOP;

            myStepper.step(0);

            break;

        default:

            // so much empty

            break;
    }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // motors
    myStepper.setSpeed(60);

    //rain sensor
    pinMode(capture_D, INPUT);
    pinMode(capture_A, INPUT);

    pinMode(switch1, INPUT);
    pinMode(switch2, INPUT);

    pinMode(lightSensor, INPUT);

    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // First, read light sensor

    rawLightValue = analogRead(lightSensor);
    Serial.println(rawLightValue);

    if (rawLightValue < 1010) {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);

        lightState = SUNNY;

        Serial.println(lightLabels[lightState]);

    } else {
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);

        lightState = DARK;

        Serial.println(lightLabels[lightState]);
    }

    // Then read rain sensor --> digital portion only, granted that you have calibrated
    // its pulsing voltage corectly. I am assuming that you are using one of these sensors:
    // https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/rain-detector-using-arduino

    if (digitalRead(capture_D) == LOW) {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);

        humidityState = DRY;

        Serial.println(humidityLabels[humidityState]);

    }

    else {
        //when it rains the clolthes re brought in
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        humidityState = WET;
        Serial.println(humidityLabels[humidityState]);
    }

    // Based on these conditions, activate the motor accordingly

    /* When it rains OR when it is dark the motors pulls the clothes in and when 
   the the clothes reaches the end it touches switch 1 and stops the motors.
   */

    if ((humidityState == WET) || (lightState == DARK)) {
        // While the switch is released, meaning that the switch has NOT been pressed:
        while (digitalRead(switch1) == HIGH) {
            activateMotor(CCW);
            Serial.println(directionLabels[currentDirection]);
        }
        // Finally, let the motors go until the swithces tell the system to stop the motor
        activateMotor(STOP);
    }

    if ((humidityState == DRY) && (lightState == SUNNY)) {
        // While the switch is released, meaning that the switch has NOT been pressed:
        while (digitalRead(switch2) == HIGH) {
            activateMotor(CW);
            Serial.println(directionLabels[currentDirection]);
        }
        // Finally, let the motors go until the swithces tell the system to stop the motor
        activateMotor(STOP);
    }
}
```